# Adding levels to a tree created from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I am trying to create a comment tree for my SPA.
So far i am able to convert the array of objects that i get from my API into a nice tree structure using

```
list_to_tree: async (docs) => {

    var tree = [],
        childrenOf = {};
    var item, id, parentId;

    docs.forEach((item) => {

        id = item.unqid;
        parentId = item.parent_id || 0;

        // every item may have children
        childrenOf[id] = childrenOf[id] || [];

        // init its children
        item.children = childrenOf[id];
        if (parentId != 0) {

            // init its parent's children object
            childrenOf[parentId] = childrenOf[parentId] || [];

            // push it into its parent's children object
            childrenOf[parentId].push(item);
        } else {
            tree.push(item);
        }
    })
    console.log(tree)
    return tree;
}
```

Now, I also want to add a level (How far is the current comment from the root comments) to each of my nodes in the tree. I want to limit nesting only till 3 levels in my SPA.

The idea is that if parentid for any node is 0, then its level is 0 otherwise the level is the parent's level + 1.

However, I am not able to do this. I want to do it in the current set of loops only. I dont want to iterate over the tree yet again just to calculate and populate the level data.

Some help would be great here.

Comment: what kind of tree you wanna build, a binary one? if so, what would be the rule for inserting left or right. An expect tree structure should be in the post.

Comment: I am just looking to convert an array of objects eg. `[{"id" = 1, "content" ="something", "parentId" = 2}, ...]` into a hierarchy of comments eg.`[{"id" = 1, "content" ="something", "parentId" = 2, "children" = [array of children objects]}`

Comment: it would be useful to see how the data looks when it starts and what you want it to look like at the end - then it would be easier to suggest solutions.